# Отображение статики, только зарегистрированным пользователям. Node.JS

Tags: node.js

Есть папка test, как ее содержание(картинки, странички) показывать только зарегистрированным пользователям? **И при этом быстро отдавать статику?**

Один из способов - это генерирование "сложной ссылки", которую другие участники просто не знают. Например, так делает Вконтакте.

[image: пример]

Хочу надежный способ: ввели пароль, можем получать статические страницы. Не ввели пароля, доступа к ним просто нет.

Поделитесь примером? Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Поставьте middleware авторизации перед middleware статики.

Comment: @AndrioSkur по какой ссылке, вы о чем?